# Nuxt 3 - Load service based in env variable through vuex store

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-bridge

I'm using nuxt-bridge in order to migrate a Nuxt 2 app to Nuxt 3.

**Nuxt 2**

There are some services that are located in a separate .js file, that have to access different url's that are provided through environmental variables. The api calls are made with axios, with a simple structure like this

> /services/service.js

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  })



export const fetchApiData = () => {
    return apiClient.get()
}
```

Then in the vuex store, there is a method that calls this service on init

```
import { fetchApiData } from '~/services/service'

export const state = () => ({
  apiData: '',
});

export const mutations = {
  SET_API_DATA(state, data) {
    state.apiData = data;
  },
};

export const actions = {
   loadApiData({ commit }) {
     const myApiData = fetchApiData();
     commit('SET_API_DATA', myApiData);
   },
};
```

**Nuxt-bridge**

In nuxt-bridge I had to change a bit the approach, as I can just call process.env on the server side. So on

> nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  components: [
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
    },
  },
});
```

And now I have to make the env variable available to the service, thus I turned it into a composable, so in

> composables/useApi.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const useApi = () => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  })

  const fetchDataFromApi = () => {
    return apiClient.get();
  };
  return { fetchDataFromApi };
};
```

And then I try to import the composable on the store, but then I get an error

```
nuxt app instance unavailable
```

What would be the way to get this service structure working? I leave a working repo https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dwx287-oygyaf?file=composables%2FuseApi.js,nuxt.config.ts,pages%2Findex.vue,store%2Findex.js.

PS: I'm aware that Nuxt 3 enforces Pinia as store management, but I would like to be able to keep vuex for the moment as I have a lot of code there, and I'd like to make a more progressive migration.

Thanks in advance!